# Why am I getting a blank screen when using shader?

Tags: libgdx, glsl, shader

I'm using this [tutorial](http://www.allpiper.com/2d-selection-outline-shader-in-libgdx) to create and draw an outline for my game `Sprite`s. However, all I get is a blank red screen. I'm very new to `Shader`s so I'm not sure if I'm missing something very trivial. My vertex and fragment shaders were copy-pasted from the above tutorial.

(Commenting on the tutorial doesn't seem to work so I was unable to seek help there.)

My code:

```
float x = 0, y = 0, height = 256, width = 256, angle = 0, outlineSize = 1f;

@Override
public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img =new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    sprite = new Sprite(img);
    loadShader();
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth(); // 640
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight(); // 480
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(h, w);
    cam.update();
}

public void loadShader() {
    String vertexShader;
    String fragmentShader;
    vertexShader = Gdx.files.internal("shaders/outline.vsh").readString();
    fragmentShader = Gdx.files.internal("shaders/outline.fsh").readString();
    shaderOutline = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    if (!shaderOutline.isCompiled())
        throw new GdxRuntimeException("Couldn't compile shader: "
                + shaderOutline.getLog());
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    cam.update();
    shaderOutline.begin();
    shaderOutline.setUniformf("u_viewportInverse", new Vector2(1f / width, 1f / height));
    shaderOutline.setUniformf("u_offset", outlineSize);
    shaderOutline.setUniformf("u_step", Math.min(1f, width / 70f));
    shaderOutline.setUniformf("u_color", new Vector3(0, 0, 1f));
    shaderOutline.end();
    batch.begin();
    batch.setShader(shaderOutline);
    batch.draw(sprite, x, y, width, height, width, height, 1f, 1f, angle);
    batch.end();
    batch.setShader(null);
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is your shader exactly as shown on that tutorial?

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes. I just ran `diff` on both to make sure again.

Comment: Try replacing that batch.draw line with sprite.draw(batch); I think you are using a batch method that modifies the origin and UVs of the sprite.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the image you're using, "badlogic.jpg" has no alpha channel. This shader draws an outline within the bounds of the sprite along the border between high alpha and zero alpha. A JPG file has no alpha channel, so there's no border to draw anything on.

By the way, you need to update your camera's width and height in `resize`, so the view won't be distorted.

That fragment shader from the tutorial could use some optimization. It has multiple dependent texture reads and multiple `if` statements. `if` statements should be replaced with calls to `clamp`. An exhaustive search of nearby pixels is probably unnecessary to detect edges unless the sprite has some super thin areas.

Comment: Yup that was it. I changed the image to a `PNG` and got the outline. But now I see that though the outline is drawn as expected, the inside of the sprite is not drawn. E.g., a green filled circle, is outlined with a blue outline, but filled with red (the "blank color") instead of green. But this, I guess, is a separate question. Thanks!

Comment: My understanding from the tutorial was that you're intended to draw the sprite a second time using this shader when you want to highlight it. That way you can draw all of your scene normally in one batch, and then the highlighted stuff in a second batch. A shader could be written to do it all in one go, but it would interrupt batching to switch the shader back and forth for the one sprite that you apply this to. Not a big deal unless you have a bunch of them interspersed throughout your stage.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks you've really helped a lot.